# Showing $N_1\times N_2\unlhd G_1\times G_2$ iff there exist $N_1\unlhd G_1$ and $N_2\unlhd G_2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

> Let $G=G_1\times G_2$ with $G_1$ and $G_2$ as groups.
>
> Show that $N=N_1\times N_2$ is normal subgroups of $G$ if and only if there exist $N_1$ and $N_2$ are normal subgroups of $G_1$ and $G_2$ respectively

My proof for 2nd direction,
$(g_1,g_2)\in G_1\times G_2$ and $(n_1,n_2)\in N_1\times N_2$ then
$(g_1,g_2)(n_1,n_2)(g_1^{-1},g_2^{-1})=(g_1n_1g^{-1}_1,g_2n_2g^{-1}_2)\in N_1\times N_2$

Comment: And what have you done or tried?

Comment: first direction not clear to me how i will obtain existence

Comment: Which direction is first and which direction is second?

Comment: if $N$ is normal subgroup of $G$ how i will find $N_1$ and $N_2$?

Comment: Note: Your quantifiers are in the wrong place. Right now you have
$$(N=N_1\times N_2\text{ and }N\triangleleft G)\iff (\exists N_1,N_2(N_1\triangleleft G_1\text{ and }N_2\triangleleft G_2))$$
which is nonsense because $N_1$ and $N_2$ are free variables on the left side, and they are not connected to $N$ on the right side.

Comment: You can't because the statement you write is a mess. It is *false* that every normal subgroup of $G$ is of the form $N_1\times N_2$ for $N_1\triangleleft G_1$ and $N_2\triangleleft G_2$. For instance, the diagonal subgroup is normal in $G\times G$ when $G$ is abelian, but is not of the given form. Find out what the **correct** statement you are trying to prove actually is first.

Answer (score 4):

The question is to show that for any groups $G_1$, $G_2$, $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G_1\times G_2$ iff $N=N_1\times N_2$ for some normal subgroups $N_1$, $N_2$ of $G_1$, $G_2$ respectively.

The claim is false. In your question, you've outlined a proof of one direction of the implication. Here is a counter-example that shows that the other direction is false:

Let $G_1=G_2=\mathbb{Z}$, and let $N=\left\{(x,x)\,|\,x\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$. Clearly $N$ is normal in $G_1\times G_2$, but $N$ is not expressible as a direct product of subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$.